# How to deal with late data while retrieving real-time bitcoin price with finnhub.io websocket API

Tags: python, websocket, streaming, etl, finnhub

I have to stream real-time Bitcoin information from finnhub.io API.
At the end of each minute period I have to print out the volume weighted average price.
The problem I face is that I don't really know how to deal with the late data.
The code below which I wrote does the job pretty lame, since it tracks the timestamp and when the seconds hit "00" it prints out the VWAP.
However this is not a good option since for the second "00" there are multiple records and sometimes data with the same timestamp comes late and the code executes again.

Here's the code:

```
import json
import websocket
from datetime import datetime

TOTAL_PRICE = 0
TOTAL_VOLUME = 0


def edit_message(message): 
    for line in json.loads(message)['data']:
        price = line['p']
        volume = line['v']
        calculate_vwap(price, volume)

        print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(line['t'] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
              "price:", line['p'],
              "volume:", line['v'])


def calculate_vwap(p, v):
    global TOTAL_PRICE
    global TOTAL_VOLUME

    TOTAL_PRICE += p
    TOTAL_VOLUME += v


def print_vwap():
    global TOTAL_PRICE
    global TOTAL_VOLUME

    print("Volume-weighted average price:", (TOTAL_PRICE * TOTAL_VOLUME))
    TOTAL_PRICE = 0
    TOTAL_VOLUME = 0



def on_message(ws, message):
    edit_message(message)

    for data in json.loads(message)['data']:
        time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data['t'] / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        secs = str(time[-2:])

        if int(secs) == 00: 
            print_vwap()


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"BINANCE:BTCUSDT"}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(False)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.finnhub.io?token=cahkkgiad3i7auh49eb0",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Don't mind the VWAP formula which is not correct at the moment. My main issue is to find the way to discard everything that comes after a given moment.

Comment: Maybe https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable ?

Comment: I have to use finnhub, thats the problem :/

Comment: I liked working with Polygon, super simple API with rate limits of 10K records per call and unlimited calls.